# Simple canvas animation: 50x50 image moving across

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, canvas

I've done this sort of programming before but It was a long while back, and despite trying for a while now, I am unable to get this working. I've tried loads of other similar codes that I've found on the internet but they don't work exactly the way I want it to! I basically want a 155x55 canvas, with a 50x50 image moving across it, simple! Despite how simple it sounds... I'm struggling... I've tried adapting my previous code but that was for bouncing balls and it was a long time ago. I'll appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

var speed = 1;

a = new Image();
a.src = "http://www.animated-gifs.eu/category_cartoons/avatars-100x100-cartoons-spongebob/0038.gif";

function frameRate(fps) {
timer = window.setInterval( updateCanvas, 1000/fps );
}


function updateCanvas() {
ctx.fillRect(0,0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
draw();
}

function draw() {
/* Add code here to randomly add or subtract small values
* from x and y, and then draw a circle centered on (x,y).
*/

var x = 0 + speed;
var y = 20;  

if (x > 150) {
x == 1;
}

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.drawImage(a,x,y,100,100); 
}

/* Begin animation */
frameRate(25);
```

**Fiddle Link:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/th6fcdr1/

Comment: Do you actually want to do this with code? Personally this is the sort of thing I just do in CSS with transform translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that your variable `x` and `y` are always reset to `0` and `20`. Your speed is `1` so your `x` is always `1`.

Since you never update the `x` position and always reset it to `0`. What you could do is to increase the variable speed by `1` at the end of the frame.

```
speed += 1
```

At first, you'll have:

```
x = 0 + 1
```

then

```
x = 0 + 2
```

... and so on.

Then you'll have to check for `speed` being above `150` and reset `speed` to 1.

Then I suggest renaming `speed` by `posX` which is more accurate. Also, instead of using `setInterval` you should be using [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame). And instead of incrementing the `posX` by 1, you should be incrementing the `posX` by `speed * elapsedTime` to get a fluent move and stable speed move which doesn't depend on the framerate.

In the end, you'd have this:

```
posX += speed * elapsedTime
var x = posX
```

Comment: You da real mvp